# LG graM 17 MODEL 17Z90P Ubuntu based distros issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I have been having unable to boot Live USB of Ubuntu and its based distros on LG Gram model as described in heading, its very capable with 16 gb RAM and 1 TB SSD. all arch based distros including fedora and DEEPIN install and work remarkably. I am very much impressed with DEEPIN and everything works as it should, sound, trackpad. I feel there is some bios setting that might allow for it be installed. But Advanced bios manu is bit complicated for me. I have disabled secured boot, platform manager. but still no luck. please anyone can guide us LG gram owners to install ubuntu based distros.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; but given the details you've provided user procedure errors haven't been ruled out; ie. did you verify your ISO after download, and particularly write the ISO to media correctly (Ubuntu ISOs can vary on release & how it's written matters, you may have used inappropriate methods or ISO writing software *versions* for the *unstated* ISOs you're using).  We can't know as you gave no specifics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Deepin is great :) If it works keep it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Ubuntu 22.10 with the following bios modifications on my lg gram 17z90n. Intel Advanced Menu, System Agent (SA) configuration, Graphics Configuration, Skip Scaning of External GFX Card=Enabled, Primary Display=IGFX, Internal Graphics=Enabled. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Insert a bootable Ubuntu 20.04 pendrive
Turn on laptop
Enter BIOS (hold F2)
Disable Secure Boot
Enter Advanced BIOS Settings (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F7)
Disable Platform Manager (will re-enable after reboot)
Disable Thunderbolt (will re-enable after reboot): Advanced -> Intel Advanced -> Platform Settings -> TCSS Platform Settings -> Thunderbolt Configuration -> Integrated Thunderbolt Support DISABLED
Check if pendrive is set #1 in boot sequence
Save
Check if above is saved
Save & Exit
Install Ubuntu 20.04
Update system (incl. language packages)
Reboot
Enjoy Ubuntu 20.04 with sound (it's been an issue before but now it works perfectly)!

In order to install 22.04, then follow my guide:
Install Ubuntu 20.04 according to my other tutorial (SOLVED How to install Ubuntu 20.04 on LG Gram 17 (2021))
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Enjoy Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Works like a charm on my 17z90p

Comment: what is the question?  and also try to use formatting; welcome to Ask Ubuntu! :)